# Weird characters when printing tree in Rmarkdown

Tags: r, tree, r-markdown

I am printing directory tree in RMarkdown using bash tool `tree`. My Rmd document looks like this:

````
---
title: "Tree"
output:
  html_document
---

```{bash,comment=""}
tree -L 1 ~/R
```
````

It renders fine in the terminal and Rmd preview.

```
/home/user/R
└── x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library

1 directory, 0 files
```

When rendered to HTML, the output has these weird characters:

```
[01;34m/home/user/R[00m
└── [01;34mx86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library[00m

1 directory, 0 files
```

I suspect it has something to do with terminal colours. I have tried a few different variations, but doesn't fix the issue.

```sh
tree -n -L 1 ~/R # Turn colorization off
tree --charset="ASCII" -L 1 ~/R # Change charset
LC_ALL=C tree -L 1 ~/R # Locale override
```

Also tried `options(crayon.enabled=FALSE)`

`R version 4.1.0, rmarkdown_2.10, tree v1.8.0`

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same issue as above.  I have a hack-workaround via `sed` to remove the unwanted characters, but surely there must be a better solution?

```
tree -n -L 2 | sed 's/\[01;34m//' | sed 's/\[00m//'
```